# Absolute probability via Conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I have recently seen the following equality:

For two uniformly (on $[0,1]$) distributed random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, possibly dependent,
\begin{align*}
P(X_1\leq a, X_2\leq b) = \int_0^{b} F_s(P(X_1\leq a|X_2=s)) ds
\end{align*}
with $F_s$ being the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $X_2 = s$.

I guess it should be trivial as it was just mentioned as a comment, but I don't see why it holds.

Answer (score 1):

More correct formulation:
$$
P(X_1\leqslant a, X_2\leqslant b) = \int_0^{b} F_s(a)\mathrm ds,\qquad F_s(a)=P(X_1\leqslant a\mid X_2=s).
$$
The Lebesgue measure $\mathrm ds$ on $[0,b]$ reflects the fact that $X_2$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. The distribution of $X_1$ is irrelevant.

To see why this hold, consider that, more generally, by definition of the conditional distribution, for every (integrable measurable) function $u$,
$$
E(u(X_1,X_2))=\int_0^1\int_0^1u(r,s)\mathrm dF_s(r)\mathrm ds.
$$
Apply this to $u_{a,b}=\mathbf 1_{[0,a]\times[0,b]}$ and use the fact that
$$
\int_0^1u_{a,b}(r,s)\mathrm dF_s(r)=F_s(a)\mathbf 1_{s\in[0,b]}.
$$

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand that when $F_s(a) = P(X_1\leq a|X_2=s)$ the equation holds. But the formulation I saw used explititly $a=P(X_1\leq a|X_2=s)$ and $F_s$ the conditonal distribution. So is $P(X_1\leq a|X_2=s)=P(X_1\leq P(X_1\leq a|X_2=s)|X_2=s)$?

Comment: To assume that $a=P(X_1\leqslant a\mid X_2=s)$ for every $a$ and $s$ in $(0,1)$ is equivalent to the fact that $X_1$ is independent of $X_2$ and is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. If this holds, one has directly $P(X_1\leqslant a,X_2\leqslant b)=aP(X_2\leqslant b)$. This does not seem to be the setting of your question. Say, what is your source?

Comment: And I know no other definition of the conditional CDF $F_s$ than $F_s(a)=P(X_1\leqslant a\mid X_2=s)$. Do you?

Comment: I saw in my lecture notes. The point that confuses me is taking the conditional expectation of a conditional expectation. The actuall note has a 3-variable setting, as in $P(X_1\leq a, X_2 \leq b, X_3 \leq c) = \int_0^b F_s(P(X_1\leq a|X_2 = s),P(X_3\leq a|X_2 = s)) ds$ with $F_s$ the conditional of $(X_1,X_3)$ given $X_2=s$.

Comment: This is the same thing just with another variable. Still I dont see how taking a conditional probabilty of conditional probabilities makes sense.

Comment: It does not (make sense). Your notes seem to rely on a deeply flawed definition of the conditional CDF $F_s$. (Unless $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent then the RHS is an extremely complicated way of writing $ab$...)

Comment: We have for a uniform on $[0,1]$ variable $P(X\leq P(X\leq a))=a$ dont we also get for $Y$ another variable on the same space (even when they are not independent!) $P(X\leq P(X\leq a|Y=b)|Y=b) = a$? This would do it.

Comment: This would be true if the function $g$ defined by $g(a)=P(X\leqslant a\mid Y=b)$ was such that $g(g(a))=a$. Which does not hold in general.